# how to insert variable into jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to insert a variable inside a jQuery selector like this example, how can I fix my problem?

```
var index = 5;
$(".tables li:nth-child('+index+')").addClass('vr_active');
```

Comment: Look at your quotes.  You need to append the variable to the string(s), not put the `+`s inside the string.

Comment: "*[How] can [I] fix my problem...?*" - and what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
its a problem man

Comment: Great: add that to the question. Can you post sufficient (*minimal*/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code to reproduce your problem with a live demo? You've got enough reputation now, and asked enough questions, that you shouldn't need to be prompted as to how to ask a good (or even passable) question any more.

Comment: Wait one minute please ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the quotes ...

```
var index = 5;
$(".tables li:nth-child("+index+")").addClass('vr_active');
```

This way, the index variable is part of a concatenation of:

- ".tables li:nth-child(" ... a string
- index ... a variable
- ")" ... a string.

Functioning **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/pv91Lesh/)**

Comment: We may need to see more code to see where the issue is ... are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Comment: I can see two possibilities ... when jQuery is not defined properly, you can get this issue, or index is not declared on the line before, as in your sample code and there is a scoping issue.  Might be something else, but these are the first that come to mind.

Comment: Created a fiddle that works.

Answer (score 1):

try to use .eq()

```
var index = 5;
$(".tables > li").eq(index - 1).addClass('vr_active');
```

Answer (score 0):

**A jQuery selector is just a string.**

So your problem is actually "How to insert a variable into a string" and this can be done in a myriad of ways, for example:

```
".tables li:nth-child(" + index + ")"
```

```
var selector = ".tables li:nth-child(${index})";
selector = selector.replace("${index}", index);
```

```
etc.
```